# htaccess rewrite url GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL:

```
https://example.com/library/capture.php?id=50
```

and I want to redirect the user with the ID he captured (GET) to this site:

```
https://example.com/app/library/capture.php?id=50
```

I am just not getting it to work. Any help is really appreciated. Thank you, guys.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: try this: `RewriteRule ^library/(.*) /app/library/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`